# Get Facebook user's profile picture prior to authenticating app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

**Summary:**

I am working on a website that connects to Facebook through the Graph API. I was asked whether I can get a user's profile picture if they are already logged into Facebook, but prior to the user authenticating the app. Is this possible?

**EDIT:**
I know you can get people's profile picture by going to `http://graph.facebook.com/USERNAME_OR_USERID/picture?type=large`, but would I be able to get a user's username or ID if they are logged into Facebook, but have not authorized my app?

---

**Details:**

According to the [Facebook API User documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/), you can get their Facebook ID without an access_token, and I know if you go directly to a user's /me URL you can see their basic information. With the Facebook ID, I can grab their profile pic.

However, when I try to call it from the website using the following code, I get an OAuthException error.

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

I'm guessing that they have to authenticate the app, but I'm looking to see if I may have missed a way of getting their profile pic.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Never mind. I found the answer. You can't get their username or ID: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7520300/facebook-app-without-prompted-authentication

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get everyone's Facebook profile picture without authentication.

You just call http://graph.facebook.com/USERID/picture?type=large.
This URL redirects you to image URL.

Edit: Querying by username is not allowed anymore, so I updated `USERNAME_OR_USERID` as `USERID`.

Comment: Thanks, cebrici. I know about this URL, but how would I get their username or ID without them authenticating?

Comment: I figured out that you can't get their username or ID without authenticating. Your answer was better written so I'll give you the answer.

Comment: I am using this is url, but its redirecting to a page with a blank image with a 'question mark'. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 2):

yes you can get..

```
http://graph.facebook.com/naseer.panhwer/picture?type=normal
http://graph.facebook.com/naseer.panhwer/picture?type=small
http://graph.facebook.com/naseer.panhwer/picture?type=large
```

Comment: Thanks, Naseer. I know about this URL, but how would I get their username or ID without them authenticating?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate an access token using an application id and secret as follows:

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={appID}&client_secret={appSecret}&grant_type=client_credentials

NOTE: Don't do this on the client side as you risk having your application getting hijacked.

The resulting token can be user to query users with the graph API without a login prompt.

Answer (score 0):

**How to get FB images w/o oauth or access tokens:**

I was trying to get only images of few members but I was stuck then wrote this snippet and worked for me,

The HTML tag

```
<img src="getFbImage.php?id=<fbid_of_the_person>&type=[small|large]" />
```

The PHP code

```
<?php

    $remoteImage = !isset($_GET['id']) ? "../images/default.png" : getImg($_GET['id']);
    $imginfo = getimagesize($remoteImage);
    header("Content-type: ".$imginfo['mime']);
    readfile($remoteImage);

    function getImg($id){
        $dom = new DOMDocument;
        $dom->loadHTML(getData($id));
        $tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
        $img = '';
        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
            $img =$tag->getAttribute('src');
            if($img=='')
                continue;
            else if(isset($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type']=='large')
                break;
        } 
        //This iteration has a lot of images try your luck.
        return $img;
    }

    function getData($id){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid='.$id);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 Firefox/39.0');
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
    }
?>
```

I only had to use a 30x30 image and I got what I wanted. Check out it also provides you a large image.

Cheers!
Joy